# ggplot2 question: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'HR' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm stuck with a ggplot2 question. This time I'm using two datasets to plot them in ggplot2 (1=6 polygons overlapping together, 2=5 GPS points). I can plot them both separately, but not together in the same plot.

Every time I do that, I get this error code: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'HR' not found

If anyone can take a second look, I'll be super grateful! Thank you.

### Code here

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(viridis)
library(ggnewscale)

#they plot well separately

poly_sf4<-st_as_sf(poly_sf3)
ggplot(poly_sf4) +
geom_sf()

roost_sf3<- st_as_sf(roost_sf2) 
ggplot(roost_sf3) +
geom_sf()

#but not together 

theme_set(theme_light())

june_only <- ggplot(subset(poly_sf4, Sequence %in% 1),#the data is the sf object,
               #set aesthetics based on the other columns/vars in the sf df
               aes(color = HR, fill = HR, alpha = HR)) + 
        geom_sf(size = 1) + 
        scale_alpha_manual(name = "HR:", 
                          values = c(0.2,0.4)) +
        scale_color_manual(name = "HR:",
                           values = viridis(3)[1:2]) + 
        scale_fill_manual(name = "HR:",
                          values = viridis(3)[1:2]) + 
        theme(legend.position="bottom", 
              legend.text = element_text(size = 15), 
              legend.title = element_text(size = 15), 
              legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"), 
              text = element_text(size=10)) 
 
 
              
june_only_roost     <- june_only + 
          new_scale_colour() + 
  geom_sf(data=roost_sf3, aes(colour=Existing), size=3) +
       scale_color_manual(name = "Existing:", 
                           values = viridis(10)[5:7])  
 
              
june_only_roost 

#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'HR' not found
```

### Data

```
#Data 01: Polygons

poly_sf3 <- structure(list(id = "NSF", area = 18.3641861686707, Month = "01: Jun 2019", 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(365367.33618389, 
    365264.754631496, 364731.911588065, 364810.96801954, 365050.261906325, 
    365346.205227799, 365367.33618389, 155179.53820745, 154761.691240949, 
    155005.189675172, 155114.59881625, 155249.352539069, 155198.343585666, 
    155179.53820745), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 364731.911588065, 
    ymin = 154761.691240949, xmax = 365367.33618389, ymax = 155249.352539069
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:32648", 
        wkt = "PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 48N\",\n    GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",\n        DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",\n            SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],\n            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],\n        UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],\n        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],\n    PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],\n    PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],\n    PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",105],\n    PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],\n    PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],\n    PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],\n    UNIT[\"metre\",1,\n        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],\n    AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],\n    AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH],\n    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"32648\"]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    Sequence = 1, HR = "MCP"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
area = NA_integer_, Month = NA_integer_, Sequence = NA_integer_, 
HR = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), row.names = 11L, class = c("sf", "data.frame"
))


#Data 02: 5 gps points 

roost_sf2 <- new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(Name = c("Ro-Giraffe", 
"Ro-Cape Buffalo", "Ro-MLR", "Ro-Night Safari Entrance (felled)", 
"Ro-Elephant", "Ro-Tram Station"), descriptio = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), timestamp = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), begin = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), end = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), altitudeMo = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), tessellate = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", NA, NA), extrude = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", NA, NA), visibility = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
NA, NA), drawOrder = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), icon = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), Existing = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "New")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(103.789426, 
103.786853, 103.787402, 103.788971, 103.785468833941, 103.788364169811, 
1.399106, 1.401148, 1.404815, 1.404159, 1.40226000499339, 1.40343003798172, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("coords.x1", 
"coords.x2", "coords.x3"))), bbox = structure(c(103.785468833941, 
1.399106, 0, 103.789426, 1.404815, 0), .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(
    c("coords.x1", "coords.x2", "coords.x3"), c("min", "max"))), 
    proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

Comment: I am unable to read the `roost_sf2` data and I get an error. It is good practice to use the `reprex` package for posting questions/answers since it ensures that the the code works on any other R instance.

Comment: nsf_roost_sf2 is not provided. The first part, "june_only" is working fine for me.

Comment: updated code! sorry for the confusion. @Rhino8

Comment: I think you need `sp` library to read `roost_sf2`

Answer (score 2):

When you build the plot that holds both data sources, don't include a data source in the first call to ggplot2.

Write something like,

```
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = first.data.source, aes(...) +
geom_sf(data = second.data.source, aes(...)) +...
```

This way, ggplot won't be looking for columns that exist only in the first data source, in the second data source.

Answer (score 2):

In `ggplot2` each of the `geom_sf` inherited `aes` from the main `ggplot()` function. Here the second `geom_sf` which you are using roos_sf2, are using `fill = HR` and  `alpha = HR`. In order to solve that, you just need to modify your code as follow:

```
poly_sf4<-st_as_sf(poly_sf3)
ggplot(poly_sf4) +
geom_sf()

roost_sf3<- st_as_sf(roost_sf2) 
ggplot(roost_sf3) +
geom_sf()

theme_set(theme_light())

# Here I changed the aes from inside of ggplot to geom_sf
june_only <- ggplot(subset(poly_sf4, Sequence %in% 1)) + 
geom_sf(aes(color = HR, fill = HR, alpha = HR), size = 1) + 
scale_alpha_manual(name = "HR:", 
                 values = c(0.2,0.4)) +
scale_color_manual(name = "HR:",
                 values = viridis(3)[1:2]) + 
scale_fill_manual(name = "HR:",
                values = viridis(3)[1:2]) + 
theme(legend.position="bottom", 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 15), 
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"), 
    text = element_text(size=10)) 

# Nothing is changed here
june_only_roost     <- june_only + 
     new_scale_colour() + 
     geom_sf(data=roost_sf3, aes(colour=Existing), size=3) +
     scale_color_manual(name = "Existing:", 
                      values = viridis(10)[5:7])  


june_only_roost
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I realise you're missing the second part of the code to get to the graph! The code above is the same as what I posted. Would you mind adding on the steps (for the GPS points) so that I can mark this as the answer?

Comment: @JoanLee I have added those parts to the code. let me know if you want to have anything else in the answer.